# Little script to choose where to SSH

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, network, ssh

Maybe I am a little dreamy, but I have many server locations, each have different servers/routers ... etc., we have them numbered from 1-83

Can someone help me building a script where I can preconfigure the IP Addressed or hostnames for these locations, and when I ssh to the location, it will prompt me to choose from my pre-configuration? something like the below prompt [done on textedit] [P.S. I am using macbook]:

ssh 15

where do you want to connect:

1. server1
2. server2
3. FW1
4. FW2
5. Router1
6. Router2

Connect to: 3
Connecting to FW1

#Normal SSH prompt after

Comment: We are not a script writing service. I use iTerm not Terminal and I have a profile for each machine and chosing that opens a new Window and sshs to that machine. Terminal has profiles as well which might work

Answer (score 0):

Found something similar, I guess I can use this, if you have something better, please share :D

```bsh
% cat 15
#!/bin/bash
select v in Server1 Server2 Router1 Router2 FW1 FW2
do 
ssh admin@$v
done

# chmod 777 15
#./15
```

Comment: What do you mean with "better"?